# escape sequences with "echo -e" not working as expected

Tags: bash, escaping, echo

I have the following 2 echo commands in a bash script:

```
echo -e "\\033[1;36m" hi there "\033[0m" # Diagnostic
 
echo  "$escape" "$msg" "\033[0m"    # -e left out
```

The first line is a simple sanity test and it works fine and produces "hi there" in bold cyan.

With the -e inserted before the "$escape", the second line does not work. I left the -e out of the second echo to see the value of $escape. Here's what I get from each echo:

```
hi there # In bold cyan
\\033[1;36m hi there \033[0m
```

Here's the issue:
When I copy and paste the second line of output onto my terminal it works fine after adding double quotes:

```
echo -e "\\033[1;36m" hi there "\033[0m"
```

But when I add the -e into the script I my default terminal color (white) is used. BTW, I did try putting double quotes around the $escape string definition in the script thinking it was the shell stripping off characters, but that did not work.

My brain is going to explode - :-)
TIA.

Comment: Your variable contains two backslashes when it should only have one. Maybe you used single quotes in the assignment unlike the double quotes in your echo statement?

Comment: Excellent observation. I copied the escapes from another program that I wrote that strips the first backslash off and that's why one program works and this one does not. For whatever reason program #2 leaves the leading backslash on. More mysteries to solve. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As that other guy pointed out above, your escape codes have two backslashes. Here is a full list of colour codes - https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting
Also, `echo` simply prints arguments followed by an end of line character. `printf` allows for formatting of a string.

Try this:
`printf '\033[1;36m%s\033[0m\n' "Hello"`.
This will give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [tput](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) instead of hardcoding the values

```
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
bold=$(tput bold)
sgr0=$(tput sgr0)

printf '%s%s%s\n' "${bold}${cyan}" "hello" "${sgr0}"
```